# Does eliminating a table view eliminate all the cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I added this

```
deinit {

    print("DEINIT A CELL!")
    ...
```

to a custom cell class.

A view controller vc has a tableView, which has dozens of those cells.

Surprisingly, when I dismiss the view controller,

```
    vc?.dismiss(animated: false) {

        print("I am even explicitly nilling it ... \n\n")
        self.vc = nil
    }
```

I DO NOT see dozens of deinits of the cell. I don't see any.

What is going on?

Apart from other problems, imagine if you have a Firebase observation in the cell. You surely want to drop all the observations when the table cv has been dismissed.

Comment: I would check if the view controllers dinit func is called. It smells like a retain cycle.

Comment: Quick test... I get `print()` outputs from `deinit`, both when using `present/dismiss` and from `push/pop`. So, yeah, sounds like you are doing something that is causing the retain.

Comment: excellent @DonMag thanks - will triple check.  note though that I am even explicitly nil'ing it  (see the code fragment) !   checking ....